# Android pausing Service, Thread, Asynctask? Using a handler with postdelayed for this?

Tags: android

I have a backgroundservice (`Service` -> `Thread` -> `Timer` -> `Asynctask`). The Timer executes the Asynctask every 5 seconds. If the Asynctask returns true a Notification is sent.

Now I want the Service to wait for 20 secs after I click on the Notification (meaning I don´t get another notification for the next 20 secs).
What "Object" needs to be stopped here? As far as I know, it is not a good idea to pause Asynctasks. So it would be either the Service oder the Thread right? Is a Handler with the postdelayed method the best solution?

EDIT 09.03.2016

```
public class NotifiyService extends Service {

    String savedsa;
    boolean value;

    protected static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    protected static final int EXTENDED_TIMEOUT = 20000;

    private HandlerThread mBgThread;
    private Handler mBgHandler;
    private MyTimerRunnable mRunnable;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mBgThread = new HandlerThread("MyBgThread");
        mBgThread.start();
        mBgHandler = new Handler(mBgThread.getLooper(), (Handler.Callback) this);
        mRunnable = new MyTimerRunnable();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences7 = getSharedPreferences("Prefsa",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        savedsa = sharedPreferences7.getString("keysa","");
        Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStarted)+ "\n" + savedsa,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBgHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mBgHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,EXTENDED_TIMEOUT);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //super.onDestroy();
        mBgHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mBgThread.quitSafely();
        Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStopped), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private class MyTimerRunnable implements Runnable{


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!value){
            try {
                URL url = new URL(savedsa);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                value = true;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            }

            if(value){
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotifiyService.this);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dummy);
                Intent intent = new Intent(NotifiyService.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotifiyService.this,0,intent,0);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setLights(Color.YELLOW, 600, 600);
                builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy));
                builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify));
                builder.setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify2));
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

            }
            mBgHandler.postDelayed(this,DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already spawning a `Thread` in the `Service`, there's no need for the `AsyncTask`.  You can use your secondary thread to do all the work.  If you'd like to use `postDelayed()` and a `Handler`, make your background thread a `HandlerThread` and create the `Handler` after the `Looper` has been started.  You can just re-schedule the same `Runnable` via `postDelayed()` and if your notification needs to change the behavior, just cancel any existing `Runnable` and set another one to be run in the desired timeframe.

Comment: What you are writing sounds good. I have to admit I´m very new to Android (6 months tops) and all I´m doing right now is more like "try and error" ;-) I´ve edited my first post with current code. What I intend to do is remove the asynctask, put all the stuff from doInBackground in the run method from my thread. Or should I use the methods from Handlerthread such as looper and so on? What do you suggest? Thx so far

Comment: I threw together a quick bit of sample code to hopefully help you out: https://gist.github.com/hiq-larryschiefer/942c73f3064cfc2a37cb

Comment: Thanks *thumbs up* today or tomorrow I will have the time to try it out. I´ll post my result :)

Comment: Ok I tried it and the app gives me a d'oh... I´ve updated my first post with the current code. The service should basically check if the url (given via sharedprefs in onStartCommand) is available. If yes it fires the notification. The webpage is from my local apache server. I´m grateful for any advice. Thx so far for your help and patience

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly what you're saying.  The sample code was just to outline an approach.  If you don't want/need to start your "timer" thread right away, then just change it to start when you need it.

Comment: What I want to say is, your answers were all correct and I thank you very  much for your help. But I have to face it that I´m not capable of doing this at this moment due to my low skills with java (been only doing C++ before).

Comment: I´ve done a little try and error and made another attempt which I´m happy with :-). When I click on the notification the service stops and resets my togglebutton so I have to click it again to start monitoring. Thats acceptable for me.